# Using custom comparator to sort a Priority Queue in C++. Keep getting invalid comparator error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, comparator, priority-queue

I am simulating CPU scheduling algorithms for a class. I have a struct called job that contains the basic info for each job, and I'm trying to order a priority queue of these jobs in order from smallest number of cycles needed to largest number of cycles needed. This is currently my custom comparator to do that:

```
class CompareJobTime {
public:
    bool operator()(job job1, job job2) {
        if (job1.cycles < job2.cycles) {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
};
```

and this is how I'm using it in the priority queue declaration:
   `priority_queue<job, vector<job>, CompareJobTime> jobTPQ;`

This is the error it keeps getting:
"Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\xutility
Line:1096

Expression: invalid comparator"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I really don't have a clue where to go from here when it comes to debugging. Thanks!

I've tried changing up the definition in a couple ways, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it. I have also tried using decltype instead of a comparator class, but I couldn't get that to work since I was writing the comparator function as a member of the class this is all being written in.

Comment: Try `return job1.cycles > job2.cycles;` instead. I think the compare you're using doesn't follow strict weak ordering. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater

Comment: So which is it? ‘Invalid operator’ or ‘invalid comparator’? You’ve posted both. And which is line 1096? You’re not making a serious effort here. BTW compiler errors are not exceptions and are not thrown.

Comment: Thank you Retired Ninja! That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Using `return job1.cycles < job2.cycles;` would push the jobs with the largest number of cycles to the front of a `priority_queue`. To get the jobs with the lowest number of cycles, use `return job1.cycles > job2.cycles;`, as @Retired Ninja suggests.